# how to display wordpress user name in color?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I have this code that gets outputs Wordpress display name:

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo  'Welcome ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
?>
```

how do output the display_name in a different color, say DARK GREEN of example? and also, if I wanted to color 'welcome' separately? how do I do that too, please? Most importantly thou, how do I color the display name?

Comment: Wrap it in tag and use `color` property for style

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do it. Wrap the texts in `<span>`'s and set the color with inline styles or add classes and set the color through CSS (recommend). This is HTML/CSS 101. I would recommend going through some "getting started" tutorials for HTML and CSS.

Comment: Well I tried and failed , can someone write the code here , based on my code above please?

Comment: I've posted an answer. If it helped, please accept it to let other know that it's been resolved. If it didn't, please comment the answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the texts in spans and add CSS classes:

The HTML

```
echo  '<span class="welcome">Welcome</span> <span class="name">' . $current_user->display_name .  "</span>\n";
```

CSS:

```
.welcome {
    color: #f00; /* Red */
}

.name {
    color: #080; /* Dark green */
}
```

*Side note:* You have a `"\n"` after your line. That creates an actual line break in the code but browsers won't render them. If you want a line break in the rendered page, you need to use the HTML tag: `<br />`.

Here's a couple of HTML/CSS tutorials you can check out:
*(I have no idea about the quality since I simply just googled "html css tutorial"*)

- https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/
- https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/hello-css/

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý - Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer :-)

Comment: Juss did , thanx .. I know HTML and CSS bro , juss didn’t know gow to implement it in this php line lol .. thanx again.